# Make button input number when pressed..android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

Ok so I have an xml layout I created in eclipse. There are 10 buttons ( 0 - 9 ). What I am trying to get is that when I touch a button, it inputs the number..so if I touch the number 1..the number 1 is showin on the screen. The main idea is like a dialer.

Comment: This question shows no research effort. Tell us what you've thought of so far, and where you're getting stuck, then you're more likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Sounds good! Where's your code that you have tried and what part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `onClickListener` class in your `Activity` source code and assign each button an `onClickListener` and make it append the `textView` value so it will display the correct number.

Example:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnOne.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnThree.setOnClickListener(this);
        // etc...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        switch (arg0.getId)
        {
            case btnOne:
                textView.append("1");
                break;
            case btnTwo:
                textView.append("2");
                break;
            case btnThree:
                textView.append("3");
                break;
            // etc...
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A question to you: *did you take a look at any basic android tutorials?*

Let your `Activity` implement the `OnClickListener`.You will need to override the `OnClick` method. The best solution is to use a `switch-case` statement:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.buttonOne:
        yourTextView.append("1");

        break;

    case R.id.buttonTwo:

    yourTextView.append("2");

        break;

         case  ..............

    }

}
```

If you have no idea what I am talking about, take a look at [this list of tutorials](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6)